# Can I run multiple instances of 'the same' Windows Store Application at once?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, multiple-instances

Is it possible to run at the same time a couple Windows Store Applications?
I have written a chat application (in C#), and want to test it on one PC, but I can't make it work.

Is there any option to do this? Or any ideas how to get around it?

Comment: What about the emulator?

Comment: @SLaks Simulator also can be opened one at the same time. It works fine, but it is still only two instances..I need more.

Comment: More than one problem here, you also can't get two Store apps to talk to each other on one machine.  There's a workaround for that, but you really ought to consider how this is going to work after you publish the app to the store.  Sounds like you ought to also start thinking about a web server that gets chatters connected.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, there is server which hand over messages between chatters, I wanted this functionality only for testing my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Windows Store apps are strictly single instanced, see this post:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdeveloperpreviewgeneral/thread/daf6f12f-b54d-4550-a70d-d92e6e06bfdc

Howerer there might be a solution, if you are owner of that app and you have access to source code and project, just build and deploy the app, change the app Name and ID in manifest file and deploy it again - it should be then shown as another app in Start screen. Note I have not tested this, but it worked fine for Windows Phone apps, so I guess it should work on Windows 8 as well?

Comment: Creating many App Packages with different Package Name and installing them works great! Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

Here are the following steps in order to run multiple instances of the same Windows Store app at once:

Preliminary steps: Ensure you have 7-zip installed.

In order to get the app's installation file, go to:

https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/whatsapp/9NKSQGP7F2NH?hl=en-us&gl=us&icid=CNavAppsWindowsApps

And search for the app you want. Copy the App's URL. Go to:

https://store.rg-adguard.net/

And paste the App link you copied and click the Checkmark button. Click the file ending in 'msixbundle', and download it.

Note: You could also just download the msixbundle file from a third-party site if the above is not working.

Download the installation file for the app. It should have an extension called ".MSIXBUNDLE"

1. Copy the ".MSIXBUNDLE" file to the root of the C directory (C:)
2. Create a blank folder and give it the same name as the app you downloaded. (For example, if you downloaded WhatsApp, name the folder as WhatsApp)
3. Right-click the MSIXBUNDLE file, click the 7-zip option, and click extract. Then set the "Extract to" option to the newly created folder. Press "OK".
4. Open the newly created folder and find the file with the ".MSIX" extension, with a name ending in 'Win32'. Right-click this, click on the 7-zip option and click extract. Then make sure the "Extract to" option is the same folder you are currently in.
5. On the option below the "Extract to" option, ensure the box is checked, and enter the name of the app you are installing, followed by "1". So it should be APPNAME 1. (For example, if you downloaded WhatApp, put "WhatsApp 1"). Then press "OK". Once the operation is complete, you will see a new folder created with the same name:(APPNAME 1)
6. Open that folder, and delete the AppxSignature.p7x file
7. Open the AppxManifest file in Notepad.
8. Find the field named "Identity Name", and some text in double quotes. It should be something along the lines of:

Identity Name="AppName.APP"

Change the value in the double-quotes to:

```
Identity Name="APPNAME.APP.1"
```

This ".1" will represent the first instance of the Windows Store app.

9. Find the following lines:

   VisualElements DisplayName="AppName"

and rename the `"AppName"` field to `"AppName 1"`.

10. Find:

    DefaultTile Shortname="AppName"

and rename the "AppName" field to "AppName 1"

11. Save the file

Note: If you want more than two instances, you will have to repeat steps 5 through 11, and call the new instances "APPNAME 2", "APPNAME 3", "APPNAME 4" and so on.

12. Open the Windows Settings app, search "Developer Mode", and ensure "Install apps from any source, including loose files" is turned On.
13. Open Windows Powershell and enter the following:

    Add-AppxPackage -path "C:\AppName\AppName 1\AppxManifest.xml" - register

Click enter and wait till the process completes:

Note: Replace `"AppName\AppName1"` with the folder names you created. You will have to repeat this step for your other instances as well.

For example:

```
Add-AppxPackage -path "C:\AppName\AppName 1\AppxManifest.xml" - register

Add-AppxPackage -path "C:\AppName\AppName 2\AppxManifest.xml" - register

Add-AppxPackage -path "C:\AppName\AppName 3\AppxManifest.xml" - register
```

Now you should be able to search the new instances you created by clicking the windows button in the bottom left-hand corner and typing "AppName 1", "AppName 2" and so on.